# Como usar links compostos - 'arquivo.html#secao'?

Tags: html, html5, arquivo, link, linkagem

Fiz o seguinte botão:

```
<a href="/../totem_app/xplaces/00_menu_vitoria_xingu.html#acru" 
target="_parent" class="bcontraste"><b>LINK</b></a>
```

para ir para

```
<a href="../acess/00_menu_vitoria_xingu_acess.html#acru" target="_parent" 
class="bcontraste"><b>LINK</b></a>
```

Porém quando eu uso um dos dois links eles vão para o diretório geral:

```
00_menu_vitoria_xingu.html# ou
00_menu_vitoria_xingu_acess.html#
```

Em ambos os casos eles não vão para

```
00_menu_vitoria_xingu.html#acru ou
00_menu_vitoria_xingu_acess.html#acru
```

Qual a forma correta para o link carregar a página "00_menu_vitoria_xingu.html" com a "seção" correta? Pois ela tem várias:

```
00_menu_vitoria_xingu.html#acru
00_menu_vitoria_xingu.html#bnpf
00_menu_vitoria_xingu.html#cars
00_menu_vitoria_xingu.html#....
```

Como faço para criar um link para abrir a *page* numa determinada seção?

Comment: Pode parecer desnecessário, mas vou perguntar. Na página que vc vai linkar tem um elemento com o ID="acru" por exemplo?. No HTML da sua página tem que ter esse elemento com o nome do ID do Link

Comment: Tem sim amigo!  Está assim:

<div id="acru" class="content active">

Comment: dib acredito que o sei problema é similar ao da outra pergunta, coloque um ./ no link. Assim, onde está " /../ " coloque " ./../ " Testa ai

Comment: @hugocsl ele abre a página normalmente, resolvi isso com a outra dica, mas ele não abre na seção correta tipo. o link é

<../acess/00_menu_vitoria_xingu_acess.html#bmnt> mas ele abre só
<../acess/00_menu_vitoria_xingu_acess.html>

Comment: Entendi, ele vai para a página, mas não vai para a ancora né... Vou pensar em algo

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, fiquei ontem matutando, não tem muito conteúdo dobre links, por ser algo relativamente simples.